# AppImage menu font size too smalll

Tags: lubuntu, fonts, menu, appimage

Menu font in Audacity AppImage recently installed in Lubuntu 22.10 is almost unreadable because too small. Similar questions have not received satisfactory answers in the past. Tweaks does fix title bar font size problem but not menu text. Does anyone know a fix? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with AppImages: FreeCAD, LibreCAD, openscad, OpenShot, etc. Solved by systemsettings5 (KDE settings) ... Appearance ... Fonts ... [chekc] Force font DPI [96]